# HX711 and weight cell, throws large negative value

Tags: arduino, sensors, particle-photon

I have successfully installed 3 weight cells to Particle Photon, using HX711. The fourth weight cell shows large negative values e.g.-69798 when a certain amount of weight is added. The weight cell should be able to measure up to 10kg, as do the other three weight cells.

Is there a possible explanation for this outcome? When lowering the weight (on all four weight cells), which are connected to a single plate, the values look good. When adding about 3-4kg on the plate, the three weight cells shows good values while the fourth shows large negative values.

Comment: Did you test if this is still true if you use another HX711 or another channel or another cell on the current channel? Do you use the same code for cells?

Comment: I fixed the problem by pooling all four weight cells and calibrated them at the same time. However, the original problem still stands..

Comment: @Lennart, check my answer below on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. Just turn the load cell by 180 degree in vertical axis. Sometimes the manufacturer puts the sticker other way around.
This should solve.